# Accessing nested data with Multer (with Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

How can I access all images uploaded that are part of an array of objects and save them to /uploads?

My req.body looks like this:

```js
{
  client: 'my_client_test',
  city: 'my_city_test',
  spots: [
    {
      photo_1: 'C:\\fakepath\\photo_1_test.jpeg',
      photo_2: 'C:\\fakepath\\photo_2_test.jpeg',
      address: 'my_address_test'
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to save all photo_1 and photo_2 of spots array.

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/admin/add", /* HERE */, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);   // undefined
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Here are the inputs:

```html
<form id="form" action="/add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- (...) -->
<div class="spot">
        <label for="photo_1_0">Photo 1:</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo_1_0" name="photo_1_0" required />
        <label for="photo_2_0">Photo 2:</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo_2_0" name="photo_2_0" required />
        <label for="address_0">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address_0" name="address_0" required />
</div>
```

Inputs are named photo_1_0, photo_2_0 and address_0 because the user is able to click a button and add another spot (photo_1_1, photo_2_1, address_1)

Index.js request

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const client = document.getElementById("client").value;
    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    const spotsArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < spotIndex; i++) {
        const photo1 = document.getElementById(`photo_1_${i}`).value;
        const photo2 = document.getElementById(`photo_2_${i}`).value;
        const address = document.getElementById(`address_${i}`).value;
        spotsArray.push({ photo_1: photo1, photo_2: photo2, address });
    }
    const data = {
        client,
        city,
        spots: spotsArray,
    };

    console.log(data); // everything looks good here
    fetch("http://localhost:3334/admin/add", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",   // should be "multipart/form-data" ?
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you making the request client-side? You need to use a `multipart/form-data` request in order for Multer to handle the uploads, it won't work with `application/json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multer works with `multipart/form-data` requests. You appear to be sending your request with an `application/json` body which I cannot recommend for file uploads (even with base64 encoding).

For something like this, I'd use Multer's `any()` handler due to the dynamic field names.

On the client-side, use field names with square-bracket notation to create a structure...

```html
<label for="photo_1_0">Photo 1:</label>
<!--        note the field name syntax  -->
<input type="file" id="photo_1_0" name="spots[0][photo_1]" required />

<label for="photo_2_0">Photo 2:</label>
<input type="file" id="photo_2_0" name="spots[0][photo_2]" required />

<label for="address_0">Address:</label>
<input type="text" id="address_0" name="spots[0][address]" required />
```

then construct a `FormData` instance to upload your files and other data

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const body = new FormData(e.target);

  const res = await fetch("/admin/add", {
    method: "POST",
    body,
  });
});
```

---

Unfortunately, Multer [isn't particularly good](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/688) at dynamic file field names but you can write a small piece of middleware using Lodash's [.set()](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) to make it easier to work with

```js
import set from "lodash/set.js";

const mapFiles = (req, _res, next) => {
  if (Array.isArray(req.files)) {
    req.files = req.files.reduce(
      (map, { fieldname, ...file }) => set(map, fieldname, file),
      {}
    );
  }

  next();
};
```

```js
app.post("/admin/add", upload.any(), mapFiles, (req, res) => {
  const bodySpots = req.body.spots; // an array of objects with `address`
  /*
  [
    {
      address: "123 Fake St"
    }
  ]
  */

  const fileSpots = req.files.spots; // an array of file pairs
  /*
  [
    {
      photo_1: {
        originalname: ...,
        ...
      },
      photo_2: {
        originalname: ...,
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
  */
});
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thanks. Hard to see why they didn't make it easy to have nested field names... Multer uses [append-field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/append-field) under the hood, but good to know that lodash can do it too!